Are there partial orders that are "weak" lattices, but which are neither join semilattices nor meet semilattices?
A lattice is a partial order where every pair of elements has a greatest lower bound and a least upper bound. I define a weak lattice to be a partial order where every pair of elements has a greatest lower bound or a least upper bound or both. I wonder, can someone give a partial order, preferably an order that has both a maximum and a minimum, such that that partial order is a weak lattice but is neither a join semilattice nor a meet semilattice?


a partial order, preferably an order that has both a maximum and a minimum, such that that partial order is a weak lattice but is neither a join semilattice nor a meet semilattice?

This should do it:

